# Linear algebra done right, Exercise 16, section 2.A

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

This question asks to prove that the real vector space of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional. In an earlier question it was proved that a vector space $V$ is infinite-dimensional if and only if there exists a sequence of vectors $\{v_j\}$ such that $$v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m$$ is linearly independent for every positive integer $m$.

I worked with the question and got this proof.

Consider a sequence of such functions $\{f_j\}$ where $f_k(x) = x^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. It's easy to see that $$f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$$is linearly independent for all positive integer $m$. Thus this vector space is infinite-dimensional.

However, when I checked the solution on this website, https://linearalgebras.com/2a.html, they constructed the function as $$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}x-\frac 1 k, & x\geq \frac 1 k; \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

I want to ask if there are any flaws in my proof.

Answer (score 2):

Proving that your sequence has the requested property is actually easy: suppose $a_0f_0+a_1f_1+\dots+a_mf_m=0$ (the constant zero function). I also use $f_0(x)=1$, not to leave poor $0$ alone.

Then, for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
a_0+a_1r+\dots+a_mr^m=0
$$
and so, if not all the coefficients are zero, the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_mx^m$ has infinitely many roots in the interval $[0,1]$, contradicting the easy to prove theorem that a polynomial has *at most* as many distinct roots as its degree.

*Proof*. A nonzero constant polynomial has at most zero roots. Suppose all polynomials of degree $k$ have at most $k$ distinct roots. Let $f(x)$ be a degree $k+1$ polynomial; if it has no roots, we have nothing to prove. Otherwise it has a root $c$ and we can write $f(x)=(x-c)g(x)$, where $g$ has degree $k$, so at most $k$ distinct roots. Thus $f$ has at most $k+1$ distinct roots. QED

Possibly the author deemed easier not to use algebra of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

There are not, but to show $f_0, f_1, \cdots, f_m$ are linearly independent is not totally trivial. (While there is no essential difference, it's better to include the constant function $1$ in the set, instead of only monomials of higher degree.)

To show $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^m a_n x^n=0, \forall x\in [0, 1]$ implies $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_m=0$, we may pick $0<x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_m<1$ in $[0, 1]$ so that $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^m \\ 1& x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^m \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1& x_m & x_m^2 & \cdots & x_m^m\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_m \end{pmatrix} = O$$

Note that the matrix is the Vandermonde matrix, which is invertible, hence $a_0=\cdots=a_m=0$. (Though I guess this is against the spirit of Linear Algebra Done Right which argues against determinant.)

Another way to do this is to use calculus. If $\sum_{n=0}^m a_nx^n=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, then $f(0)=a_0=0$, and $f'(0)=a_1=0$, $f''(0)=2!a_2=0$ and so on.

Now perhaps it's easier to understand the motivation for defining $f_k$. If we can find a family of functions $f_1, f_2, \cdots$ associated with a sequence of points $x_1, x_2, \cdots$ such that $f_i(x_j)=0$ iff $i\not=j$, then it's easier to show $f_i$'s are linearly independent.

Instead of the $f_k$'s cited from the web, we may also use $$f_0=1, f_1=(x-1), f_2=(x-1)(x-1/2) \cdots, f_m=\prod_{n=1}^m(x-1/n)$$ Now if $\sum_{n=0}^m a_nf_n=0$, let $x=1$, we know $a_0=0$, then let $x=1/2$, we get $a_1=0$ and so on.

Comment: I see, but I'm not very clear on the motivation part. Can you explain more on how can we prove that such families of functions are linear independent? Btw thanks for answering !!!

Comment: If $f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k=0$, then plug in $x=x_i$, we get $f(x_i)=a_if_i(x_i)=0\Rightarrow a_i=0$.

Comment: @RyanHu This is basically a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra which states that a polynomial of degree $m$ has exactly $m$ (complex) roots. The linear combinations you are examining are actually polynomials of degree $m$ so they can't have infinitely many roots.

Comment: @Giorgos_Giapitzakis that's not accurate. The FTA contains two parts: First show the existence of a single root, then use the long division to get $m$ roots or factorization. The second step is rather trivial compared to the first one, and can be incorporated here to replace the Vandermonde, which is done in egreg's answer. My point is, this takes work compared to other constructions.

Comment: @Justauser The FTA is just the existence of *one* root. The rest is elementary algebra of polynomials, valid in any field: each time you have a root, you can factor and reduce the degree. Simple induction to show the polynomial is a product of linear factors. I believe that stating the FTA as the existence of as many roots as the degree counted with their multiplicities hides the real meaning. And for this application the FTA is definitely unneeded.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis This has nothing to do with the FTA.

Comment: @egreg I totally agree, but people can call whatever equivalent proposition as FTA as they like.

Comment: OP asked for some motivation. I never said this is "equivalent" to the FTA. I was trying to provide some motivation as to why we would choose the monomials instead of some other family of functions. The reason here is that the linear combinations examined are polynomials so they cannot have infinitely many roots. Of course, this is way easier to prove without even talking about the FTA, but it can also be seen as a consequence of it. Again I was talking about motivation and not some equivalent proposition to FTA as @Justauser (rudely) said.

Comment: @Justauser Yea I got it. That approach seems to be universally sufficient to construct such a sequence of functions. Thank you!

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Is this what you mean? The linear combination of $x, x^2, \ldots, x^m$ is a polynomial of $k$ degree, where $k$ is the largest integer such that $a_k$ is non zero, so it cannot have infinitely many zeros in $[0,1]$ unless every coefficient is zero. I think this approach helps me understand it as well, thank you!

Comment: @RyanHu Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in[0,1]; x_i\neq x_j, i\neq j$, and let
$$
p_j(t)=\frac{\prod_{i\neq j}(t - x_i)}{\prod_{i\neq j}(x_j - x_i)}.
$$
Now note that $p_j$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $p_j(x_j) = 1$ and $p_j(x_i)=0$ if $i \neq j$. Finally observe that $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i p_j(x_i) = a_j$$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$.