# Axler LADR, ex. 2.A.16

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, alternative-proof

I tried Ex. 2.A.16 of Axler‘s ["Linear Algebra Done Right"](https://linear.axler.net/).

**Prob:** Prove that the real vector space of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional.

I found some solutions on the net and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502496/linear-algebra-done-right-exercise-16-section-2-a), on this page. Since my solution is different, I ask if my line of argumentation is correct.

**Sol:** The vector space of all real valued polynomials on the interval $[0,1]$ is an infinite-dimensional subspace of the real vector space of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$, since polynomials are continuous on $[0,1]$. By contraposition of thm.2.26 (if a subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then $V$ is infinite-dimensional) the vector space of all continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ must be infinite-dimensional as well. $\blacksquare$

That $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is infinite-dimensional was proved in the text. I am accepting the reduction to the interval $[0,1]$ without proof. But such a proof would follow the same line as for all polynomials. Any comments and critique is welcome.

Comment: This is certainly a correct argument if you assume to know that the polynomial functions are infinite dimensional.

Comment: The fact that some subspace $P$ of real-valued functions is infinite-dimensional does not necessarily imply that $P$ restricted to $[0, 1]$ is finite-dimensional. (Construct a stupid counterexample: say some infinite-dimensional space of piecewise functions which are constant on $[0, 1]$). You might need to invoke whatever lemma was used to prove that $\mathcal{P}(R)$ is infinite-dimensional again (I don't know what the book uses). But for instance: if $a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x^1 + a_0 = 0$ on $[0, 1]$, then it has infinitely many roots, and so is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

"comments and critique" :

(1) You should list out the Exact Statement of the theorem you want to use : "thm.2.26" is neither sufficient nor self-contained in the context of your MSE Post.

(2) You have to tweak 2.26 to limit it to $[0,1]$ which itself might be more unnecessary work.

(3) You have to ensure that 2.26 did not use what you are trying to prove here, other-wise it will be circular logic & hence invalid.

(4) It is not necessary to go to 2.26 involving Infinite-Dimensional Sub-Space to get the Contradiction.
We can just use $Dim(U) \le Dim(V)$ not involving infinity [[ https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Proper_Subspace_is_Less_Than_its_Superspace ]]
That itself is enough to prove what you want , like this :
In Case the Continuous-real-functions $Dim(C)$ were not Infinite-Dimensional , then the Polynomial SubSpace $Dim(P)$ too must not be Infinite-Dimensional to let $Dim(C) \ge Dim(P)$
Since $Dim(P)$ is Infinite , $Dim(C)$ must also be Infinite

(5) Your Alternate thinking also gives ideas about various interconnections between various theorems.

(6) SUMMARY : Your line of argument is correct (over-all your Proof is nice too) but not complete. When you fill in the missing pieces & make simplifications , it might still be longer than what is given else-where like https://linearalgebras.com/2a.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I‘ll try to post a completed form, including them. I knew comment (4), but didn‘t want use it since dimension wasn‘t discussed at this point of the book.